# starting minikube using cntlm gives Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 to docker env

Tags: minikube, http-proxy

I am behind a corporate proxy and need to use `cntlm`.  Hence my proxy env variables are as follows

```
https_proxy=http://localhost:3128
http_proxy=http://localhost:3128
```

Now when I try to start minikube using `minikube start` I get the following errors

```
❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 to docker env.

❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 to docker env.
```

However since I'm using `cntlm` the proxy should be `localhost:3128`.  How do I get over this problem.  I tried the following as well without any success and get the same error

```
minikube start --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128 --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Comment: Have you read the following documentation page?: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I had CNTLM listen on IPv6 localhost interface ::1 and told minikube to proxy via that one:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://::1:3128  ...
```